# Issues with startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Tags: ios, ios7, cllocationmanager

I am using “startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges” method of CLLocationManager. This method is running well in background state and active state but not when the app is terminated. The documentation of the above method says that:

“If you start this service and your application is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the application into the background if a new event arrives.”

But I am not able to implement it in my code. I have gone through a lot of QnA in Stack Overflow and have also tried a few solution but haven’t yet succeeded. 
My iOS version is 7.1.

My code:

ViewController.m

```
//Created sharedInstance of my class

+(ViewController *)sharedInstance { <br/><br/>
    static ViewController *sharedViewController = nil; <br/> 
    @synchronized(self) { <br/>
        if (sharedViewController == nil) { <br/>
            sharedViewController = [[self alloc] init]; <br/>
        } <br/>
    } <br/>
    return sharedViewController; <br/>
}
```

//Button click initiates the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method

```
- (IBAction)clickedGetCurrentLocation:(id)sender { <br/>
    locationManager.delegate = self; <br/>
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [self startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]; <br/>
}

- (void) startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges
{ <br/>
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]; <br/>
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{ <br/>
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error); <br/>
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; <br/>
    [errorAlert show];

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; <br/>
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *currentLocation = locations[0];

    if (currentLocation != nil) { <br/>
        longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]; <br/>
        latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]; <br/>
    }

    // Reverse Geocoding <br/>
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) { <br/>
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) { <br/>
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject]; <br/>
            addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country]; <br/>            
        } else { <br/>
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);  <br/>
        } <br/>
    } ];

    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init]; <br/>

    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location Changed To (%@, %@)", [latitudeLabel text], [longitudeLabel text]]; <br/>
    localNotification.alertBody = message; <br/>
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date]; <br/>
    localNotification.alertAction = @"Location Change Detected"; <br/>
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/India"]; <br/>
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{ <br/>
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) { <br/>
        [[ViewController sharedInstance] startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]; <br/>
    }    <br/>

    UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

    if (locationNotification) { <br/>
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0; <br/>
    }

    return YES; <br/>
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{ <br/>
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState]; <br/>
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) { <br/>
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil]; <br/>
        [alert show]; <br/>
    }

    // Set icon badge number to zero <br/><br/>
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

Comment: I advice you show some of your code and explain what works and which part doesn't work. Your question is otherwise very hard to answer.

Comment: @Volker, I have added code to my question. Please have a look at it

Comment: i think you have to restart location services when the app is started due to a location change:  Upon relaunch, you must still configure a location manager object and call this method to continue receiving location events. - i don't see that in your app delegate code where you just start monitoring sig location changes again without having setup a location manager.

Comment: @Volker. One more thing, I have tested this app in iPhone simulator and iPad 2. Should I change the testing device bcoz this method is related to cell tower??

Comment: @Volker, in AppDelegate.m, I have called a method "startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges" from ViewController.m. I have copied the method above under ViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

When IOS receives a location update, and respawns your app after terminating the app, letting it know it respawned due to a location service. then you need to re-start the background location service,in diddidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
        [[LocationController sharedInstance] startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions contains other code for the view activation. Should it be executed or I just need to execute startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges?

Comment: more over, my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not called when my app in background and significant location change triggers the app resume.

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will call only when the app is start again after termination or when app is start first time and whtever code for view will be executed normally but what you need to do is just add this startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges whnever app is start again

Comment: @BhavikKama, can you tell me on which device should i test my code. Will it work in simulator and iPad 2? or should i test it on iPhone?

Comment: You should Test this on IOS Device rather then simulator

Comment: @BhavikKama just finish my tests and confirm that behavior is exactly as you said. With the locationkey in options we need to register for significant location changes in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 0):

From my experience Apps won't be launched from termination due to significant location changes however GeoFencing will do the trick.
If you set a fence that the user enter/exit you will be launched from termination to response to the event ~30 seconds of background time (depend on the device type).